# How to force an Exchange 2010 Edge server to deliver incoming messages only to Exchange 2010 Hub servers?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2007, exchange

I have a mixed Exchange infrastructure where there are some Exchange 2007 Hub servers and some Exchange 2010 ones; they are all in the same Active Directory site.

There are also some Edge servers; they are all running Exchange 2010, and they are subscribed to the organization.

I discovered from the tracking logs that incoming messages are being delivered by the Edge servers to both the Exchange 2007 and the Exchange 2010 Hub servers; since all mailboxes are on Exchange 2010 servers, those messages need an additional hop to reach their recipients.

How can I configure the Edge servers to route inbound messages only to Exchange 2010 Hub servers? The inbound Send Connector is useless here, as it doesn't specify its target servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inbound send connector on the Edge server is actually pretty useful in this scenario. You just need to configure it to use smarthost routing, and set the Exchange 2010 Hub Servers as smart hosts:

```
Set-SendConnector -Identity "MyInboundSendConnector" -DNSRoutingEnabled:$false -SmartHosts hub2010server1.domain.com,hub2010server2.domain.com
```

You might want to read [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232082.aspx) to get a better grasp of how traffic flow between transport servers can be configured

Comment: Can I do that? That connector is automatically configured with a smart host setting of "--". I never tought this was even *allowed* to be changed.

Comment: Just create a new Send Connector using the `New-SendConnector` cmdlet, and disable the automatically configured one